# Batarang extension giving no results whatsoever

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, batarang

I have tried using it on local site, on hosted sites, even on the Angular sites, and all I get is a listing of the HTML with Angular. No scopes, no models, nothing useful whatsoever. I'm assuming it's supposed to help develop with Angular in Chrome, but, nothing.

Has anyone found a reason for this?

Using

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m
AngularJS v1.2.26
AngularJS Batarang 0.7.4

Answer (score 16):

I found this old version and it works.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek

Comment: Now the page is 404.

Comment: @Douglas Ferguson, could you update the link please? it's not working now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I rolled back to the previous version.  if you follow [this link](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang), it will give you the instructions - I will add them here also in case the link moves.

**Installing Previous Versions**

> 1. Download and extract one of the files from the [Batarang releases page on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/releases)
> 2. Navigate to chrome://chrome/extensions/ in Chrome
> 3. If you've installed Batarang from the web store, disable or remove that version
> 4. On the top right, check the checkbox for "Developer mode"
> 5. Click "Load unpacked extension..."
> 6. Select the directory where you extracted the extension
> 7. Close and re-open any inspected tabs

The above was taken from the same link as I posted.

Comment: Hm. Tried this with several different versions, now I'm just getting a blank area under the Angularjs developer tool. Thoughts?

Comment: Having the same issue as @MaxRocket, these instructions from the readme simply do not work. The link posted by Douglas works perfectly and now I got my performance tab again!